# "while" logic operator makes program not work

Tags: python

I've been learning Python for about 4 days and I'm just dealing with my first problem.

```
import random
number=random.randint(1,10)
count=1
guess= int(input("Enter your guess between 1 and 10 : "))

while number != guess:
    count = count + 1

if guess == number:
    print("That is my number !")

while guess < number:
    guess = int(input("Too low :( Guess again ! : "))
    if guess == number:
        print("That is my number !")

while guess > number:
    guess = int(input("Too high :( Guess again ! : "))
    if guess == number:
        print("That is my number !")
```

My program just print only first input line and then nothing.

```
Enter your guess between 1 and 10 :
```

Why is that?

```
while number != guess:
    count = count + 1
```

When I delete this two lines, it works perfectly.

Comment: Fix your indentation. That's the first thing you should learn about Python: indentation is critical.

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing the meaning of `while` and `if` .  `if` does something once, `while` keeps doing it over and over and over.

Comment: Remove the tab from from the line where "while" starts. And as suggested by others, read about indentation.

Comment: edit : count = count + 1 is intended now  and while number != guess: tab removed, and still nothing.

Comment: `while number != guess:` repeats until that condition is no longer true. But since you never change the values of those variables inside the loop, the condition never changes, so it repeats forever.

Answer (score 2):

In Python whitspace is significant, because the loop was not indented correctly, the your program did not work as expected. The corrected code looks like this:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,10)
count = 1 
guess = int(input("Enter your guess between 1 and 10 : "))

while number != guess:
    count = count + 1

    if guess == number:
        print("That is my number !")

    elif guess < number:
        guess = int(input("Too low :( Guess again ! : "))

    else:
        guess = int(input("Too high :( Guess again ! : "))
```

Comment: The nested `while`s should just be `if`.

Comment: If number == guess then the program doesn't enter the while loop and the code doesn't make sense.

Comment: There should be only one `if guess == number:` out of the `while` loop

Comment: Okey I see what i did wrong, I feel so stupid now, Thank you all for answers ! I'm motivated now.